# Why the package (.wl) and .nb behaves completely different

Tags: notebooks, packages

I am developing an application in one part I am checking the if the functions are constant or not. I am using a couple of lines of code (it is possible that there is another way of doing it) but the code behaves differently when I use as a package instead of in a .nb file. The notebook code is

```
FunCons2[var1_, var2_, var3_, var4_] := Module[{fields}
  , fields = Flatten[{var1, var2, var3, var4}]
  ; consz =  fields /. z -> {a, b}
  ; consz
]

f1 = 1;
f2 = t^3 + (z - 1) (z - 2) + E^-t Sin[z];
f3 = {-1 + E^-t Cos[1], 2 (1 + E^-t Cos[2])};
f4 = Limit[f2, t -> 0];

FunCons2[f1, f4, f3, f2]
```

The output as you can see t is replaced a and b

> ```
> {  {1, 2 - 3 z + z^2 + Sin[z], {-1 + E^-a Cos[1], -1 + E^-b Cos[1]}, 
>    {2 (1 + E^-a Cos[2]), 2 (1 + E^-b Cos[2])}, 
>    {a^3 + (-2 + z) (-1 + z) + E^-a Sin[z], b^3 + (-2 + z) (-1 + z) + E^-b Sin[z]}}
> }
> ```

and the package version is

```
Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]],"CheckCons.wl"}]];

f1 = 1;
f2 = t^3 + (z - 1) (z - 2) + E^-t Sin[z];
f3 = {-1 + E^-t Cos[1], 2 (1 + E^-t Cos[2])};
f4 = Limit[f2, t -> 0];
CheckCons`FunCons[f1, f4, f3, f2]
```

The package

```
BeginPackage["CheckCons`"];

FunCons::usage="";

Begin["`Private`"];

  FunCons[var1_,var2_,var3_,var4_]:=Module[{fields,a,b},
    fields=Flatten[{var1,var2,var3,var4}];
    consz=fields/.z->{a,b};
    consz
  ]

End[];



EndPackage[];
```

And the output is

> ```
> {
>    {1, 2 - 3 z + z^2 + Sin[z], -1 + E^-t Cos[1], 2 (1 + E^-t Cos[2]), 
>     t^3 + (-2 + z) (-1 + z) + E^-t Sin[z]}
>  }
> ```

The problem is replacing `z`  with `a` and `b`. Inside the package the code does not replace it. I don't know why or how to avoid that.

Comment: The reason I am not really happy is still I am not understanding the reason why it is happening like this. If you look at the Print from the package for the fields. `{1,2-3 z+z^2+Sin[z],-1+E^-t Cos[1],2 (1+E^-t Cos[2]),t^3+(-2+z) (-1+z)+E^-t Sin[z]}`   t and z are still the variable no private or global why I can't replace t or z directly. Even when you look at the output of Variables[Level[fields,{-1‌​}]][[1]] it is {} or  z or t.

Comment: @Erdem clear the kernel, run the package and check ``?? CheckCons`FunCons``.

Comment: @Kuba it is `Attributes[FunCons]={Locked,Protected,ReadProtected}`

Comment: @Erdem Don't use it, there aren't any above. They are not needed. And without ReadProtected you will see that the definition uses Private symbols.

Comment: @Erdem I've put some edits to the linked question. Let me know if they helped. And please learn [how to create minimal working examples](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2144/5478).